# Map a key with a condition

Tags: key-bindings, location-list

`LanguageToolCheck` and `LanguageToolClean` are 2 commands used in **[vim-languageTool](https://github.com/dpelle/vim-LanguageTool)** plugin.

`LanguageToolCheck` command check and list out spelling errors of your text. And `LanguageToolClear` will clean the error list. During error checking mode. User then can use :lne to jump to the next error. I wonder how to map the **n** to :**lne** command when `LanguageToolCheck` command is executed and map back to normal function (jump to next highlighted) for **n** when `LanguageToolClear` is executed

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but well known plugin [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) by Tim Pope adds short mappings for many commands, including `:lnext` which is the one you're after.

The vim-unimpaired mappings generally use `[` and `]` as its direction ("previous" vs "next", or "on" vs "off") followed by a single letter to identify the object (`l` for the location list.)

So you have [`]l`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/4afbe5ebf32ad85341b4c02b0e1d8ca96a64c561/doc/unimpaired.txt#L27) for `:lnext`.

`]l` is not as short as just using `n`, but it might be something for you to consider, since it doesn't involve changing the behavior of `n` during an operation (it's quite possible you'll end up wanting to search in between `LanguageToolCheck` and `LanguageToolClear`.) You may also find the other mappings from vim-unimpaired to be quite useful, it's definitely among the plug-ins I tend to recommend.

Comment: Thanks a lot fibranden, it would be so cool to have some sort of smart n that can detect the user intentions to search the `coc-diagonostic-next` if using the vim-coc, search the next spelling error when using `LanguageToolCheck` and search for the next highlight if highlight set is true. I would like to getting to know vim better and write a plugin for that

Comment: @SLN Go for it! If you want to learn vimscript this is one of the most highly regarded guides available: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/